# Upgrade packages WebApi with odata, ver 3.7 ODataModelBuilder reference issues

Tags: odata, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to upgrade my application(MVC) packges from v2.3 to latest v 3.7
Issues i'm facing is the ODataModelBuilder cannot be resolved any more as it is looking for the system.web.odata and the new version installed by package manger due to dependancies is Microsoft.AspNet.OData.

It seems the AbpWebApiODataModule still rederences the System.Web.Odata?

```
    public override void PreInitialize()
    {


        Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().HttpConfiguration.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);

        Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApiOData().MapAction = configuration =>
        {
            configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().HttpConfiguration.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", configuration.Modules.AbpWebApiOData().ODataModelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
        };



        var builder = Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApiOData().ODataModelBuilder;


    }
```

The type 'ODataConventionModelBuilder' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.OData, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue for `Abp.WebApi` at [aspnetboilerplate/issues/2670](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2670)

The fix has been released with [v3.8](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/releases/tag/v3.8.0)